# Proving vector space property $(-c)*v=c*(-v)$

Tags: vector-spaces, field-theory

Let $V$ be a vector space with a field $F.$

Prove that $\forall v \in V$ and $c \in F$ $(-c)*v=c*(-v)$ using properties of vector spaces and fields.

$(-c)*v = (-1*c)*v = (c*-1)*v = c*(-1*v) = ...$

I'm not how to show $-1*v=-v$

Comment: Perhaps $v + (-1)*v = 1*v + (-1)*v = (1 - 1 )*v = 0*v = 0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

To prove $-1\cdot v=-v$, you can just notice that $v+(-1\cdot v)=0$, doing the following:
$$v+(-1\cdot v)=(1-1)\cdot v=0\cdot v=0,$$
so you have proven that $v+(-1\cdot v)=0$, so this means that $(-1\cdot v)$ is the inverse by addition of the element $v$ (commonly called *opposite*), denoted $-v$, so we can conclude that
$$-1\cdot v=-v$$

Comment: This depends on $0v=\vec0$ being a vector space axiom, which I think it usually is not.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen that is also to prove though since $v + 0v = (1+0)v=v$ so adding $-v$ to both sides gives $0v=0$.

Answer (score 0):

How this is done depends on the exact set of axioms you are using. There are the "obviously necessary" ones that vector addition is associative, commutative (maybe this can be proved from the others, but let's assume it is given), has a neutral element $\vec0$, that scalar multiplication satisfies $1v=1$ and $\lambda(\mu v)=(\lambda\mu)v$, and two distributive laws (for scalar and vector addition). It does not look like these suffice to prove the mentioned property; I would guess one needs at least one of the two additional basic properties.

The first possibility is to add $0v=\vec0$ as axiom. Then one can show that $(-1)v$ is the additive inverse of $v$ using the distributive law: $(-1)v+v=(-1)v+1v=(-1+1)v=0v=\vec0$. So every vector is invertible for addition and we can write $-v$ for the additive inverse $(-1)v$ of $v$. And from there is suffices to apply the multiplicative property $$(-c)v=(c*(-1))v=c((-1)v)=c(-v).$$

The second possibility is to take as axiom that every vector $v$ has an additive inverse, written $-v$; this together with the other properties of vector addition simply means that with just addition we get an Abelian group. This is in a sense more natural, and is for instance the approach taken on the Wikipedia for vector spaces. But it means we must work a bit to show that $0v=\vec0$ for all vectors $v$. One way to do this is through the intermediate claim that $v+v=v$ implies $v=\vec0$; this is simply obtained by adding the additive inverse $-v$ to both sides and doing the obvious simplifications. Then to prove $0v=\vec0$ it suffices to show $0v+0v=0v$, but that can be done using distributivity: $0v+0v=(0+0)v=0v$. This shows the two extra axioms are equivalent (given the others), and the remainder of the argument is now of course the same as above.